# Why doesn't Xcode 3.2.3 stop debugging my application when I hit home in the Simulator?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Good Day!

i have installed xcode latest in my snow leopard, now i have a question that when i run my project in xcode, and then stop it from simulator, but the xcode still shows that the app is running. so if i have to run it again, it will ask to rebuild like it was running and i want to run it again. i want to know that whether its an issue or bug, or its ok to be like this. and there is no issue in that.

One more thing, that now when i stop, the debugger is not sent any "KILL" or "END" or anything to show that app is ended.

please looking forward for this problem.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 4.0 allows backgrounding, so your app can still be running when you quit it.

If you double-click the home button, tap-hold on your app icon, and press the red `-`, it will quit. You can also press <kbd>⌘.</kbd> from Xcode to stop it.

Comment: ok, lets say if the app is running how can i kill it from xcode that it does not go to background and just finish as it is suppose to end ?

Comment: Consider using `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`, see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097244/exit-application-in-ios-4-0).  Then when you're confident it's being handled properly, switch it back.

Comment: @jbm If you want the app to terminate after you click the home button, you can add the `Application does not run in background` key to info.plist and set its value to `YES`. Hope this helps.