# Close iPhone app from within the app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

Is there a way to close the iPhone app from within the app? A client asked me if there was a way to close the app by pushing a button in the app, without manually doing it by double tapping the home button and then press-hold the app icon and then hit the - sign.

Apparently,  the client wants to build an app which uses bluetooth and ANT+ devices which are battery hogs and wants the ability to quickly close the app.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You could `exit()` in response to a button press event, however somewhere in the guidelines it says that this is not allowed for an App Store app. I have seen apps which do exactly that, though.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/355168/251760

Comment: how'bout setting the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` Info.plist key to true?

Comment: UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend I'm going to give that a shot. Thanks

Comment: Note: UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend will disable the multitasking feature of your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from quitting from a button within the application being against the [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27), it isn't even [recommended behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097244/exit-application-in-ios-4-0).

But if you still want to close your app. Use 'exit();'.

Comment: And this isn't even an answer.

Comment: No, it's not, it's meant as a stern warning that such apps should not pass the iTMS approval process and is, therefore, something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking you should just make the button dispose of the Bluetooth and other 'battery hogs'. You might even make the app smart enough to turn it off based on certain events like when the user leaves the app or when a certain function is completed.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is against Apple's Human Interface Guidelines. If you still want to do so, use the C function `exit();`. But for the user this will look like the application crashed, so I wouldn't do so, even not on an non-AppStore app!

Comment: The same applies to you it does to hd1.  This is not an answer, make this a comment.