# UIAlertView button to display viewController

Tags: objective-c, button, uialertview, viewcontroller

I've been looking all over the internet for a solution to this problem, yet to find one that I can understand. So here it goes.
I have my iOS application, on which on the first launch of the application, will display a UIAlertView. I want one of the buttons to send the user to a new viewController to view some essential information.

I have gotten my UIAlertView configured properly, here's the code for the actionSheet:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex == 0)
{

//Code to open a new viewController???


}

if (buttonIndex == 1)
{

//User can exit the application if they do not wish to continue

exit(0);    }

}
}
```

I have a viewController created named webViewViewController, that's what I want users to reach when they tap the first button. Any ideas on how to do this? I have ARC disabled, other 'solutions' i've come across keep giving me errors.

Thanks all, would appreciate some guidance here.

Comment: First of all, `exit(0)`: never!
Tip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335848/exit-application-when-click-button-ios
Then, to instance a new UIViewController, Apple Doc should be useful.

Comment: I've been a bad boy, I'll change that. Could you help me tho?

Comment: To show an alert view you have to first launch a rootView..

Comment: I have a UIAlertView, read my question

Comment: what i have understand is  you have screen A and B . You have alert view on screen view .And if you click one of the button then it should  go in B .Right ?

Comment: Oky... i know, You already have been got answered of This Question but also [see This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534513/unknown-receiver-in-xcode-project/14534579#14534579)

Answer (score 0):

If your current viewcontroller is in  a Navigation Controller:

```
UIViewController *myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
myViewController.title = @"My First View";
//to push the UIView.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

And never use exit(0)!

Comment: Would it be possible to make it a modal view controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex == 0)
{

 NewViewController *controller=[[NewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
            self.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];



}
```

drasick has given sufficient answer but if you need  to use model view controller refer above.

Comment: Receiving 'unknown receiver' and 'unknown type name', my view controller name is webviewviewcontroller, any ideas?

Comment: forward declare class @class className instead on #import in the .h file and do #import in .m to avoid circular dependancies

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
UIViewController *yourViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

to push a modalViewController.(This is depriciated in iOS 6, but will work)