# UIAlert does not work in IOS 7 (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode5

I have this alert confirm box in swift, it works perfectly in IOS 8, but it does not work in IOS 7, how can i resolve it please ?

Here is my code

```
 var refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Cerrando la aplicacion!", message: "Seguro que desea Cerrar ?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Si", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        exit(0)
    }))
    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        println("ho hace nada")
    }))
    presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Read the docs for UIAlertController. Specifically the "Availability" section. Where it says "Available in iOS 8.0 and later" it means exactly what it says.

Comment: What do you mean not work? `UIAlertController` is introduced in iOS8. For earlier version, as it stated in the doc, use `UIActionSheet` or `UIAlertView`.
Note that you can't do an "exit(0)" if you want to be published in AppStore.

Comment: I hadn't spotted the `exit(0)`. This is a BIG NO in iOS apps. In fact, it will probably get your app rejected. The user should never exit the app this way. That is what the home button is for.

Answer (score 4):

From the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html):

> Availability Available in iOS 8.0 and later.
>
> A `UIAlertController` object displays an alert message to the user. This
>   class replaces the `UIActionSheet` and `UIAlertView` classes for
>   displaying alerts. After configuring the alert controller with the
>   actions and style you want, present it using the
>   `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method.

So for earlier versions of iOS, use `UIActionSheet` or `UIAlertView` (from your example, `UIAlertView`).

Also, you can't quit the app with an `exit(0)` if you want to be published in the AppStore, it doesn't respect Apple's Guidelines. More explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335848/exit-application-when-click-button-ios/14335936#14335936).