# How to use navigator.app.exitApp() to exit application in cordova on iOS platform?

Tags: cordova

I have an application built using cordova but I don't know how to add exit/stop function to exit the application.After looking around in google and other sites I got clue to use `navigator.app.exitApp()` but it didn't work for me. How can I solve this?

here is my code:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
            var network = navigator.connection.type;

            if (network === 'none') {


                    $cordovaDialogs.confirm('Attention' + '\n' + 'You have no internet connection', '', ['Review Settings', 'Exit'])
                        .then(function(buttonIndex) {
                            // no button = 0, 'OK' = 1, 'Cancel' = 2
                            var btnIndex = buttonIndex;
                            if (btnIndex == 1) {
                                $state.go('register');
                            } else {
                                navigator.device.exitApp();
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: show your code first

Comment: navigator.app.exitApp() only works on android, you shouldn't quit an iOS app programatically, it's against the apple HIG for iOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

navigator.device.exitApp() does not work in iOS...it is ignored. It may in Android (typically with some mods, but that's another issue).

You can modify an existing plugin or create your own plugin and add a method to call native ObjC exit(0) or [[NSThread mainThread] exit]. Apple frowns upon including a way for user's to exit an iOS app.

Answer (score 2):

Don't. It's not a part of how iOs apps work. And if you use it there is a good change your App will not be approved in the Apple Review process and **will be rejected from the App Store.**

Other SO answer: [Exit App](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14335899/4421627)

Apple itself: [Themes & UI](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/themes/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-exit

Add in the build.xml the plugin:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-exit" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
```

In your javascript code:

```
if (cordova && cordova.plugins)
{
    cordova.plugins.exit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

cordova plugin add https://github.com/FRD49/iOS-ExitApp.git

use this plugin and simply call
`navigator.app.exitApp();`