# How can I programatically close an ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, exit

I've tried the two following approaches to close my ionic app but non has worked.

1.

```
closeApp(){
    this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(999999, () => {
       navigator['app'].exitApp();      
    })
}
```

In this approach, when I click on the back button, the app is disappeared, but it's in the list of the background running apps. This doesn't help me, because I need the app to be completely closed and the user be forced to reopen the app by clicking on its icon.

2.

```
closeApp(){
   const { App } = Plugins;
   App['exitApp'];
}
```

in this case, nothing happens, i.e., I stay on the page.

Is there any other approach or plugin which I can use?
I am working with capacitor: 3 and testing on android 12.

Comment: use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-exit

Comment: I am not sure how to use this plugin. After installation,I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656764/how-to-use-navigator-app-exitapp-to-exit-application-in-cordova-on-ios-platfor) to use it, but I don't have a `build.xml` file. I've several `config.xml` files, in which one I have to add the plugin (if it's necessary)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';

  ExitApp() {
  App.exitApp();
  }
```

try this

Comment: This didn't solve the problem. Its behavior is like the second approach I've explained above.