# Force to start App after came back from background. Swift 3

Tags: swift3, init, foreground

I have some problems with my interface when I open my app, go to background and finally return to foreground. So I want to force my app to start the app always, when I came back from background.
I saw that Clash Royale game is working like that.
I am developing with swift 3

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/3098252/1072229 ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what your Home Page looks like that you want to load up after returning from the background but you should be able to use the functions in the AppDelegate to be able to set values and load up Scenes or Views as needed when returning from the background state or to be able to set the desired view as the app gets closed down.

Here is a list of the functions that are already built into the AppDelegate.

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

Comment: For some reason applicationWillResignActive didn't format as code. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that @LeoDabus. For some reason it wasn't accepting my edit.